# SQL Job runs without it schedule and renaming or deleting it causes other jobs fail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent, jobs

I recently migrated the SQL 2008 to SQL Server 2016. I started noticing a strange issue where one of the SQL Job is causing the failure of other jobs. This job is disabled and there is no schedule and it keeps running on its own. When I rename or delete this job, Other jobs starts failing. As soon as I create the job with same name, The other jobs starts working. I am not sure what could be relation here. Note only specific job fails. Can anyone please help me find the cause here.

Comment: Do other jobs fail reporting they can't find the job you renamed or disabled?

Comment: No they just start failing as soon as I rename or delete that job

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run profiler in here to see if something is running manually your job with very specific filters like the job name.

Comment: Ok I will try that also